# Problem with captions and titles in Serbian cyrilic

Tags: captions, chapters

Using

```
\usepackage{cmsrb}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc} %better to use T1, but OT1 will also work
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}
```

before `\begin{document}` and `\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont` as first line  after `\begin{document}`, I manage to obtain text in Serbian cyrilic but problems remain in Chapter names, captions, headers. Contents name is still in latin also. What to add to get full cyrilic text.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple, just use

```
\usepackage[T1,OT2]{fontenc}
```

instead of `\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}`.

The last listed encoding will be the default, and that is basically the problem. The definition of the class commands such as the `\section` contains the command `\normalfont`, and that command will change the font encoding to the default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You're using somewhat outdated methods.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Београд}

Београд је главни и најнасељенији град Републике Србије и привредно, 
културно и образовно средиште земље. Град лежи на ушћу Саве у Дунав, 
где се Панонска низија спаја са Балканским полуострвом. Београд је 
управно средиште Града Београда, посебне територијалне јединице са 
својом месном самоуправом. По броју становника четврти је у југоисточној 
Европи после Истанбула, Атине и Букурешта.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{\huge AAA}

\caption{Ово је цифра}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[Text courtesy of Wikipedia](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4)

If you insist in the older method,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{cmsrb}
\usepackage[T1,OT2]{fontenc} %better to use T1, but OT1 will also work
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Beograd}

Beograd je glavni i nainaseljeniji grad Republike Srbije.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{\huge AAA}

\caption{Ово је цифра}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]